# Customize spring validation error

Tags: spring, validation, customization, bean-validation

I want customize the spring validation error for

```
    @NotNull
    @Length(max = 80)
    private String email;
```

but I'm unable to do it.
What are the step to follow?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

The [JSR 303 default message interpolation algorithm](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#section-message-interpolation) allows you to customize messages by supplying a resource bundle named ValidationMessages.  Create a `ValidationMessages.properties` file in the classpath containing:

```
javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message=CUSTOM NOT NULL MESSAGE
javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=CUSTOM SIZE MESSAGE
```

This changes the default message for the `@Size` constraint, so you should use the `@Size` constraint instead of the Hibernate-specific `@Length` constraint.

Instead of changing the default message for all constraints, you can change the message for a specific constraint instance.  Set the `message` attribute on the constraint:

```
@NotNull(message = "{email.notnull}")
private String email;
```

And add the message to the `ValidationMessages.properties` file:

```
email.notnull=E-mail address is required
```

Comment: I think a worthy sidebar to add here is that you can get the min and max values of the size like `javax.validation.constraints.Size.message=Length must be between {min} and {max} characters`

Comment: how do i do internacionalization with this properties file? ValidationMessages_<locale>.properties ?

Comment: @Chin Huang, What if the values of {min/max] may change dynamically? Can one specify as message parameter {The minimum value is {provided_at_runtime}}, where provided_at_runtime does not referencing an annotation attribute

Comment: How do I change the color to red?

Comment: @Gonçalo, Yes, That seems to be the way. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gkahi.html

Comment: @santafebound, Spring <form:errors> tag has a cssClass property to customize styles.

Answer (score 0):

By Spring I am assuming you mean Spring MVC.

From the below reference 
http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/mvc.html

Here you go -

You create a validator class -

```
public class UserValidator implements Validator {

    public boolean supports(Class candidate) {
        return User.class.isAssignableFrom(candidate);
    }

    public void validate(Object obj, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "firstName", "required", "Field is required.");
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "lastName", "required", "Field is required.");
    }
}
```

Put in any validation text you want in the above field.

In the JSP you will need the following tag -

```
<tr>
    <td>First Name:</td>
    <td><form:input path="firstName" /></td>
    <!-- Show errors for firstName field -->
    <td><form:errors path="firstName" /></td>
</tr>
```

This way any validation error for `firstName` will be printed.

Comment: I'm using Annotation Validation like @NotNull. So where are stored the message in Spring jar? I think i need to edit them

Comment: @apache-fan I down vote your answer because OP says about modern JSR303-style validation and not about old spring-specific.