# Check whether few fields are empty in a Large POJO and if they are empty add some custom Error message

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-mvc, pojo

I am new to Spring and I am writing an API ,where it can consume upto 71 values in the POJO . What i would like to do is check for 20 fields in the  POJO which are mandatory and if they are null , I want to add custom error message saying this a mandatory filed and it cant be Null(I have a custom class where i can add Error messages ) . How can i do this , is there a way to loop over this items , is there a way where we cann add annotations like `@NotNULL` or i need to manually do an if else check on this items if they are null and add the error message . I was writing if else cases checking whether they are empty and i got really curious to simplify and reduce the lines of code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805168/customize-spring-validation-error

Comment: I am pretty sure you just want to have  POJO field validation using javax.validation.constraints.*;. From what I am reading this should help. If you have more information I can give you a better example. 

@NotNull(message="Name is mandatory")
 private String name;

Let me know what you are using on the front end to capture and display the error message. Good Luck!

Comment: I am going to expose it purely as an API . No front end . Could you shed some more light on the javax.validation.constraint

Comment: Eclipse shows me an error on message part

Answer (score 1):

I would go with @NotNull or a custom constraint ([Custom constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4805168/customize-spring-validation-error)). As for the loop you could also do that but i would deprecate it. Check out the  `java.lang.reflect` package to learn more.