# Spring - same custom message for multiple validation annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

Is it possible to use the same custom message for multiple annotations in Spring 4+ framework.

In my case, I would like to show the same message for @NotNull and @NotEmpty annotations.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "First name cannot be empty.")
@NotNull(message = "First name cannot be empty.")
```

Comment: What happened when you added this in your app?

Comment: You don't need NotNull in this case, NotEmpty covers null.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. Message is not used as an identifier in the system so it is possible. I would suggest to use `ValidationMessages.properties` and

```
@NotEmpty(message = "{first.notnullorempty}")
@NotNull(message = "{first.notnullorempty}")
```

See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4811273/5585182 to prevent copy pasting the same message over and over again.